# How to change the Aptana terminal theme?

Tags: themes, aptana, aptana3

Just installed Aptana Studio 3 (Version 3.0.7) on Eclipse Indigo.

Trying to modify Themes, to have simple colours on Terminal/Console; ie just FG and BG.
But unable to remove highlights from text. <del>Cant attach screen as I dont have enough rep :(</del> *Update: screenshot added, see below* :)

Console section didnot match the list of Scopes given in Wiki ([Current Theme Scopes](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Current+Theme+Scopes#CurrentThemeScopes-ConsoleScopes))
So tried to add Console.output which had no effect. 
Also verified that there are no bash profiles defined in my system.

Is there any other way to remove those highlights?

Thanks in advance for any replies

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change colours in terminal window use *ansi.** theme scope.

If anyone wonder how to inverse terminal colours then you have to add *ansi.white* entry with *ansi.white* scope with black **foreground** color selected. Then add *ansi.black* entry with *ansi.black* scope with white **foreground** color selected.

This works fine in Aptana Studio 3.4